# Confused with dates and days in cron jobs

Tags: date, cron, days

I am having trouble understanding how dates and days work together in a cron job.

Say I have the following command:

```
0 23 5 1 3 COMMAND
```

This translates to 23:00, on 5th of January, on Wednesday.

The problem is, that January 5th is a Sunday. How exactly will this command work out? Is the command going to be executed for both January 5th AND for every Wednesday on the month January? Or will it execute just the '5 1' bit?

I am really sorry if it is a really basic question and possibly stupid but to me it really does not make any sense.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands are executed by `cron` when the `minute`, `hour`, and `month of year` fields match the current time, and `at least one of` the two day fields (`day of month`, or `day of week`) match

Ref: [Man Page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab)